# Apply the explode modifier for usage in the game engine

Tags: animation, game-engine, particles, logic-bricks

Is it possible to use the animation data generated by the *explode modifier* for an animation in the game engine? If you start with the object you want to blow up, subdivide it, add a particle system, set the settings to make the particles go boom, then add the explode modifier, You will have a nice explosion. However, particle systems are not supported in the game engine, so Even if the object you want to blow up is set to play the animation using the *action* actuator, nothing will happen in the game engine. I have tried applying the *explode modifier*, but all that does, is create a mesh based on the particle system data for the selected frame. Is there a way to use the animation data from the explode modifier as a action in the game engine?

Comment: There is an addon for particles in BGE http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?241656-easyEmit-*Update*-13-06-2013

Comment: Right, I just wanted to mention it, because it could be an alternative.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ideas for how to make a cube explode into smaller cubes in game engine](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28766/ideas-for-how-to-make-a-cube-explode-into-smaller-cubes-in-game-engine)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not possible to do using the explode modifier through the particle system. However, you can use a rigid body simulation to simulate the debris, and animate each piece. Those animations can then by played in the game engine.

[image]